# Check if cell contains strings in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have an Excel sheet with a lot of different entries (expenses) that I want to classify. To do that, I created another sheet with different entry categories such as groceries, night out etc., and I put each in a column.

So this is my expenses sheet:

| Description | Value | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Card - Foetex purchase on 3/10 | 350 | ? |
| Card - Mikkeller purchase on 3/10 | 350 | ? |

And this would be the categories sheet:

| Groceries | Night out |
| --- | --- |
| Foetex | Mikkeler |
| Irma | To Oel |

What I want to do is to have the Category defined on the categories sheet (Groceries and Night Out) on the 3rd column of the Expenses sheet. So what is in the categories sheet would be a substring of the text on the description column of the expenses sheet. So if, for example, the description has "Foetex" in it, then the Category should be Groceries.

I have tried Match, countif etc., but to no avail.

Does anyone know a way out of this?

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Comment: 2008 (Office 365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this answer I have made the following assumptions:

- Sheets are named "Expenses" and "Categories", and are in the same workbook
- Both the above tables start at `Cell A1`

The formula in Sheet "Expenses" `Cell C2` (your '*Category*' column) should be:

`=CONCATENATE(IF(COUNTIF(A2, "*" & Categories!A$2:B$3 & "*")>0, Categories!A$1:B$1, ""))` then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to apply it as an array formula.

Replace `Categories!A$1:B$3` With your categories range if it is longer or wider, make sure that second range `Categories!A$1:B$1` stays stuck to the top row though.

And Remember to use [absolute references](https://exceljet.net/glossary/absolute-reference) to save the range changing when you copy the formula down the rest of the category column.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. All the assumptions are correct, however I am getting #SPILL! error. This is how the formula looks like when adapted to the real sheet:
=CONCATENATE(IF(COUNTIF(G5, "*" & Categories!A$2:R$20 & "*")>0, Categories!A$1:R$1, ""))

Comment: Entering ctrl + shift + enter worked :) Thanks!