# Merge Excel sheets with different structure with Talend

Tags: excel, talend

I have one excel file with this structure:

sheet1 - column1 column2 column3 column4

sheet2 - column1 column3 column4

what i want is to merge both sheets into one, by column name (i.e sheet2 will have null values on column2 but column1 and column3 should merge)

so I should have one sheet with column1 column2 column3 Only

what talend does is that he takes first 3 columns from both sheets and merge them
i.e col1 with col1, col2 with col3 and col3 with col4.

i wanna do this dynamically, i dont really have only 2 sheets, i have a lot, and a lot of excel files, example is just for explaning

Data looks like this
[image]

All sheets have commun columns, but some sheets have more columns some less

Comment: In which cell does the `column name` located? would u mind sharing some sample values/file? (you may [edit] this question and add sheet1 & sheet2 [tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) in it)

Comment: @p._phidot_ I've edited the post, columns name is located in the first row, thanks

Comment: I assume this is Sheet1.. how does Sheet2 (with missing column) looks like?

Comment: same, minus some columns

Comment: Does 'minus' means [ all column in Sheet2 have exactly the same header as Sheet1 but no entries.. ] or [ there is some column header in Sheet1 that is not present in Sheet2 ] ? ( If u share an example of Sheet2 will help to clarify this )

Comment: Since we can only see Sheet1, we cannot really see how `col1 with col1, col2 with col3 and col3 with col4.` works . You can make up some values and share the tables like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68665947/check-if-cell-contains-strings-in-a-list). Use the 'table' link I shared above to create those tables in the post.